# How can I have my DateTimeField filled in automatically for my admin entries?

Tags: django

I have a `date_added` field for my entries and it's frustrating clicking the date and time when filling these in. I want this to happen behind the scenes and I don't want these to even show up.

I've googled around and tried searching SO but was unable to find a snippet of how this can be done when I save my form.

Here's the relevant bit from `admin.py`:

```
class BugForm( forms.ModelForm ):
    class Media:
    #js = ( 'http://static.arounds.org/wmd/wmd.js', )
    js = ( 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.2.3/mootools-yui-compressed.js', 'http://static.arounds.org/js/moowmd.js', 'http://static.arounds.org/js/wmd-config.js' )
    css = {
        'all': ('http://static.arounds.org/css/wmd.css',)
    }

    class Meta:
    model = Bug

class BugAdmin( admin.ModelAdmin ):
    fields = ['name', 'slug', 'excerpt', 'summary', 'date_added', 'poster', 'categories', 'status']
    prepopulated_fields = { 'slug' : ['name'] }
    form = BugForm
```

I'm aware that I'll have to probably specify `exclude = ('date_added',)` and define a `def save()` function, but I'm not sure of the specifics needed for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want this to happen behind the scenes and I don't want these to even show up.

IMHO the best way to do this is edit the model and set [`auto_now_add=True`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) for the  `date_added` field. This assumes you have access to edit the model. You'd do something like:

```
class Bug(models.Model):
    ...
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This will solve both your problems: it will fill in the date time automatically *and* will not show up in the Admin app. From the docs:

> Automatically set the field to now when the object is first created. Useful for creation of timestamps. Note that the current date is always used; it's not just a default value that you can override.

I'd like to note that there is a complementary [`auto_now`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) that you can use for tracking updates. Setting `auto_now=True` will be useful for `date_updated` fields if any.

Comment: Normally I'd recommend `default=datetime.datetime.now` over `auto_now_add`, but since the OP doesn't want the field to show up at all, the latter is the correct solution this time.

Comment: @Daniel: Doesn't the "default" case get the time from Python, and the "auto_now_add" case tells the database to get the time with the SQL NOW() function?